# Mapping a HashMap lookup over Index from Enumeration of a String in Rust

Tags: string, rust, hashmap, enumerate

I would like to look up some strings in a `HashMap` by first iterating through a string, enumerating the index of the character, and using that position as my lookup for the Key in the `HashMap`

This is what I am trying:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main()
{
    let weight = HashMap::from([
         ("1", 8),
         ("2", 7),
         ("3", 6),
         ("4", 5),
         ("5", 4),
         ("6", 3),
         ("7", 2),
         ("8", 1),
         ("9", 0),
         ("10", 9),
         ("11", 8),
         ("12", 7),
         ("13", 6),
         ("14", 5),
         ("15", 4),
         ("16", 3),
         ("17", 2)
    ]);

    let s = String::from("Hello World");

    let weights: Vec<_> = s.chars()
                           .enumerate()
                           .map(|(i, c)| weight.get( &(i+1).to_string() ).unwrap_or(&0))
                           .collect();
    dbg!(weights);
}
```

But am getting confused with the errors regarding how to perform the map properly. I understand that .chars().enumerate() creates an iterator of pairs (idx, char) on the string, but I want to use the idx, add 1 to it, then use that value as the key lookup in my HashMap. Where am I going wrong?

Error I am receiving: the trait `Borrow<String>` is not implemented for &str.

However, I thought by casting to String via .to_string() I could perform this?

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&str: Borrow<String>` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:76:56
   |
76 | ...                   .map(|(i, c)| weight.get( &(i+1).to_string() ).unwrap_or(&0))
   |                                            ---  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Borrow<String>` is not implemented for `&str`
   |                                            |
   |                                            required by a bound introduced by this call
```

Comment: What is the question? Does this give the wrong result? What should the result be? Or is there a compiler issue? If so, please include it.

Comment: To make this compile, replace `&(i+1).to_string()` with `&*((i+1).to_string())`. This is slightly tricky, but we have many similar questions already, so I'll look for a useful duplicate.

Comment: So you can use `&(i+1).to_string()[..]` or (from the comments) I prefer `(i+1).to_string().as_str()`.

Comment: @kmdreko Care to explain why this is works?

Comment: To use `.get()` on your hashmap, the type you pass, `&T`, must satisfy `&str: Borrow<T>`. But in your case, there is no implementation for `&str: Borrow<String>`. There is one for `&str: Borrow<str>` and `String` can automatically deref to a `str` but it won't since the argument is generic. The examples above are ways to explicitly convert from a `&String` to a `&str`.

Comment: The tricky part is that _usually_ you can pass an `&String` if the compiler wants an `&str` just fine, since the compiler will perform a deref coercion. However, such a coercion only works if the compiler knows that the target type is `&str`. In this case, the compiler only knows that the target type is some `&T` satisfying `&str: Borrow<T>`. It's not known a priori that `T` must be `str`, so no coercion happens.